# Friends with the opposite gender

Tags: halal-haram, relationships, men-women, friendship

I have a best friend from the opposite gender, we talk online through chatting apps and we have normal conversations at school, we are never alone together always in a public setting, we have never touched before. Is this friendship haram or halal?

Comment: If Allah has commanded to lower our gaze in front of non-mahrams, how do you think gossiping with them is acceptable?

Answer (score -1):

That has friend of opposite gender not talk about in directly then at the time online and indirectly conduct (not see that face ) is imposible

Answer (score -1):

The Quran does not forbid male and female friendships despite many people claiming it is forbidden. Provided you are not alone together and you are observing appropriate behavior like not touching etc it is not haram for you to be friends.

You should however be mindful of temptation and truthful with yourself and Allah as to your intent. If you are tempted to become more than friends with a boy and fear you may fall into sin then it is best you do not keep that friendship.

Answer (score -4):

It is common question from the young muslim girls/boys.

You can find the best answer from [that video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rS4Yocu--8U).