# Is talking to a Non-Muslim opposite gender haram?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, relationships, men-women, social-media

We knew each other from social media and we have been talking for years..
A few males and a few females.. (im a female)
**Expect one male, all others are muslims..**

and its noted that now when i talk to them, i dont feel happy anymore.. like it causes me stress.. but i also dont want to stay apart from them.. however when i leave, it gives me a peace of mind.
**What do u think i should do?**

And when i talk to them.. My imaan becomes weak :(

tho i still havent figured out why..

and there is always debates going on with the muslim friends and non muslim friend about why he should become a muslim.. tho they insult each other while they are at it.. and he debates why they should not trust on the religion.. its been stressful

These days I have been getting more interested in Islam Alhamdhu'lilah and because of a post i saw that says we shouldnt talk to opposite genders.. I cutted my contact with them.. but i feel bad.. **so i dont really know what to do..**

**Is talking to them Haram?**
we treat each other as Family..like brothers and sisters
and we know each other's all the secrets and thoughts.. so on..

**So what do you think i should do in this situation?**

wasalaam Alaikum Wa'rahumathaullah Wa barakaath

Answer (score 0):

It is not the first Question about talking/chatting. You find answers opposing each other [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/are-we-allowed-to-have-friends-of-the-opposite-gender) and [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50206/friends-with-the-opposite-gender?rq=1). The answers depend on how strictly Hadith is generalised, and whether a chat is considered to be "public". About personal physical contact only two persons of opposite sex, answer is quite clear, see [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8185/does-the-quran-or-sunnah-directly-forbid-male-female-interactions-aside-from-se?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Do I need to say Goodbye to them when i Cut off contact? In Islam it says Its not good for a person to not talk to another for more than 3 days.. so i would like to know is it a sin to cut off people without saying goodbye? Do i need to explain the reason to them?

Comment: If you think the kind of contact falls into a category that is not acceptable, as you have been there for suche a long time, it is adequate to tell the reasons to your colleges and say good bye.

Comment: The ruling of "more than 3 days" are for blood relatives. Also, the ruling is about cutting contacts. Not talking frequently is different from cutting contacts.
And there is nothing that says you have to "goodbye" to them.
And most importantly, you mentioned your imaan becomes weak when you talk to them. That is a bad indicator sister. It is better to surround yourself with people who would make you imaan stronger or at-least not make it weaker.
And it doesn't matter if you treat each other like family, if they are not your mehram, you should not talk to them (muslim or non-muslim)

Comment: @Jeschu read clearly what she has mentioned about "not talking for more that 3 days"

Comment: @ForTheSakeOfAllahAlone Indeed got it wrong, I didn't realise the double not.